# Where are Observable subscribers executed

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I am trying to understand Angular observables and whether subscribed functions are called asynchronously or in the Javascript event loop. For example, if I make the following call:

```
    this.http.get<Result>('http://www.example.com').subscribe(result => {
        // Do something with result that affects the UI
    });
```

I understand that the actual network request and response i.e. the `get` is done asynchronously but is the function `result => {}` executed within the same asynchronous task or on the Javascript event loop?

The reason I ask I elude to in the code comment: `// Do something with result that affects the UI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the async requests callbacks and subscribed functions are also added to the event loop, specifically, to the task queue and pushed to the stack when it's empty to be executed. [Here](https://christianlydemann.com/are-observables-async/) is a more detailed explanation and referring about it to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) great video for Philip Roberts about the event loop.

Comment: The video was good. It made me understand that Javascript only has a single thread and asynchronous tasks are only achieved with the help of the browser and only for specific cases. The code and callbacks we write all run on a single thread.

Comment: @Kerry, yes it's an interesting topic to learn more about. A lot of memory management and performance issues live here.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the type of observable, there are hot and cold observables. The example you give will emit after a http call is made, an observable made with of or a behaviour subject will run synchronously as soon as the subscription is made.

Take a look at the source code to a behavior subject

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/BehaviorSubject.ts

and you will see next is called on subscribing.

It all depends on the type of observable.

Answer (score 0):

[https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L84)

> null  By not passing any scheduler, notifications are delivered
>   synchronously and recursively. Use this for constant-time operations
>   or tail recursive operations.

The default is synchronous, and the http observable doesn't set the scheduler

[angular http observable](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L84)

But to your question, I assume you are setting a property of the component that is used in the template. Unless you are using onPush in your component, setting the value in the subscribe block will display the change.

Unless you are using the values from the subscription in multiple places, the best way to use a subscription in a template is to do something like this:

```
myexampledata = this.http.get<Result>('http://www.example.com')
```

then in the template

```
{{myexampledata | async}}
```

Subscriptions and unsubscribe will be handled by the framework. If you need to change the shape of the data in some way for display, you can map the values to what you want

```
myexampledata = this.http.get<Result>('http://www.example.com')
.pipe(
     map(returnedvalue => returnedvalue.whatiminterestedin)
)
```

If you set a property of the component that you use in the template, then the angular change detection will handle the update.

Comment: I suppose my question is 'what thread executes the callback function'. After reading Muhammad's question I realise that any javascript code I write (other than AJAX which defers to WebAPI's within the browser) will run on on the single thread. Javascript only has a single thread.